# Publishing message on JMS queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

i am new to JMS and going thru the example of  [Active MQ Hello world](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world). Say i have a scenario whenever i make entry
under employee table in DB, i have to put the message in queue.here is the producer code snippet from hello world example

```
public static class HelloWorldProducer  {
        public void createMessageOnQueue() {
            try {
                // Create a ConnectionFactory
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

                // Create a Connection
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();

                // Create a Session
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
                Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

                // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

                // Create a messages
                String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + this.hashCode();
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

                // Tell the producer to send the message
                System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message.hashCode() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                producer.send(message);

                // Clean up
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my question is if i close the connection and session, will it close the queue also? If yes,what will happen if message has  not been consumed yet?

Second question is if i need to publish the message on same queue(i.e "TEST.FOO") second time , do i need to call `createMessageOnQueue` method second time. If yes, will it not create  new queue with `session.createQueue("TEST.FOO")?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my question is if i close the connection and session, will it
>   close the queue also? If yes,what will happen if message has not been
>   consumed yet?

message will still be on queue. No such thing as 'closing a queue'.

> Second question is if i need to publish the message on same queue(i.e
>   "TEST.FOO") second time , do i need to call createMessageOnQueue
>   method second time. If yes, will it not create new queue with
>   session.createQueue("TEST.FOO")?

session.createQueue("TEST.FOO") does not necessarily create queue, it just get a reference to existing queue.

javadoc of session#createQueue()

> Note that this method simply creates an object that encapsulates the
>   name of a topic. It does not create the physical topic in the JMS
>   provider. JMS does not provide a method to create the physical topic,
>   since this would be specific to a given JMS provider. Creating a
>   physical topic is provider-specific and is typically an administrative
>   task performed by an administrator, though some providers may create
>   them automatically when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The queue is created once and only you can delete it manually.
Once the message is sent to a queue, it will wait on the queue until it's consumed (unlike topics).

You don't need to re-create the message if you want to send it twice. But then again, why would you send it two times?

I feel that your problem might be solved using JMS transactions.